# Android ViewPager OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: android, android-viewpager, out-of-memory, android-imageview

I have a ViewPager implemented and I am getting a OutOfMemory Exception in the instantiateItem Method:

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Context context = QPhotoGallery.this;
        mImageViewForPager = new ImageView(context);
        mImageViewForPager.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

        mImageForView = mImages.get(position);

        File imgFile = new  File(mImageForView.getPath());
        if (imgFile.exists()) {
            mImageViewForPager.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
            if (mImageForView.getOrientation() == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90)
                mImageViewForPager.setRotation(90);
            if (mImageForView.getOrientation() == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180)
                mImageViewForPager.setRotation(180);
            if (mImageForView.getOrientation() == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270)
                mImageViewForPager.setRotation(270);
        }

...
}
```

This Line:

```
mImageViewForPager.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
```

is causing the exception. Somebody have an idea?

Comment: image dimension issue plz add proper dimension image or use high configuration device

Comment: store the image to new path with custom dimensions and use that image in your code, or use Picaso to load image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### OutOfMemory Exception

Thrown when a request for memory is made that can not be satisfied using the available platform resources. Such a request may be made by both the running application or by an internal function of the VM.

> You are dealing with large bitmaps and loading all of them at run
>   time. You have to deal very carefully with large bitmaps by loading
>   the size that you need not the whole bitmap at once and then do
>   scaling.

Problem is here

```
mImageViewForPager.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
```

**imgFile** is too large **(Big Size)** . That's why have problem . Reduce Its size(*Resolutions*) .
You can add **`android:largeHeap="true"`** in your manifest .
Hope this helps .

> https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: You can add `android:largeHeap="true"` in your manifest & `reduce image size` .

Comment: @davidOhara Move ahead .Glad to hear .

Answer (score 0):

When loading images into the memory, keep in mind that you should always think about scale it down, checkout the Android Official tutorial - [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).